# Jest get summary of passed and failed tests in json, xml or html file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently using flag `--coverage` to get in html a nice summary of test coverage in the project:

```
node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --coverage
```

Is there anyway to just get the amount of passed and failed tests in a json, xml or html file?

I'm using react-native + enzyme.

Answer (score 3):

Ok passing the --json option gives me back a JSON with a summary of the tests, command:

```
node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --json --outputFile=example-name.json
```

The option `--outputFile=example-name.json` will tell the command to save all results in `example-name.json` in rootDir

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.

The option `--outputFile=example-name.json` will save all results in `example-name.json` in root dir

Comment: What does this post add to [CommonSenseCode's 2017 answer](/a/45712619)?